# Как спарсить String?

Tags: java

Есть `String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Android";`
Как убрать все что находится после последнего "/" ? Будь то "/Android" или что то иное...

Comment: Интересно, откуда вы все берете это слово "спарсить" ? Распарсить же, не? Ну или разобрать на худой конец...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Используйте lastIndexOf:

   ```
   if (null != str && path.length() > 0 )
   {
       int endIndex = path.lastIndexOf("/");
       if (endIndex != -1)  
       {
           String newstr = path.substring(0, endIndex); // not forgot to put check if(endIndex != -1)
       }
   }
   ```
2. Либо в кратце:

   ```
   String whatyouaresearching = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/"));
   ```
3. Либо можете использовать [apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.substringBeforeLast(str, separator)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringBeforeLast(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

   ```
   StringUtils.substringBeforeLast(path, "/")
   ```

Пример на [ideone](http://ideone.com/HjQ1Ak).

<sub>[Источник.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828313/remove-string-after-last-occurrence-of-character-android-java)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

```
path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Добрый вечер.
Так же можно использовать метод split();

```
String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Android";
    String []con = path.split("/");
    String newpath = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < con.length - 1; i++){
        newpath += con[i] + " ";
    }
```